# Authentication middleware using Dart Shelf

Tags: authentication, server, dart

I'm using the [shelf](https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf) package from [Dart](https://dart.dev) to implement a backend for the [realworld-example-app](https://realworld-docs.netlify.app/docs/specs/backend-specs/introduction). According to the [specs](https://realworld-docs.netlify.app/docs/specs/backend-specs/endpoints), some routes require authentication, some don't, and in others the authentication is optional. My idea is to write a [middleware](https://github.com/dart-lang/shelf#handlers-and-middleware) that would decode and validate the token and put the `User` in the request context if it was found, or else return [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) status in case of errors.

However, as I'm not very experienced with `Dart`, `shelf`, or `Dart` patterns, the approach I ended up implementing was awkward: I hardcoded some routes that would require authentication as a `static` property of the `AppRouter` class below, require a `List` of routes as a parameter to the `authorize` middleware function, and then call it in the `createServer` function. This approach is leads to code duplication, non-obvious coupling and is ugly. Do you have better ways of doing this?

https://github.com/marcusmonteirodesouza/dart-shelf-realworld-example-app/blob/f323b015e3b0a6abbe8ac49170c66de9c32fe931/lib/src/app_router.dart

```dart
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/jwt_service.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/users_handlers.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/users_service.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

class AppRouter {
  // Routes without the starting slash
  static List<String> routesRequiringAuthorization = ['api/user'];

  late UsersHandlers _usersHandlers;

  AppRouter(
      {required JwtService jwtService, required UsersService usersService}) {
    _usersHandlers =
        UsersHandlers(jwtService: jwtService, usersService: usersService);
  }

  Handler get router {
    final router = Router();

    router.post('/api/users', _usersHandlers.registerUserHandler);
    router.post('/api/users/login', _usersHandlers.loginUserHandler);
    router.get('/api/user', _usersHandlers.getCurrentUserHandler);
    router.put('/api/user', _usersHandlers.updateUserHandler);

    return router;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/marcusmonteirodesouza/dart-shelf-realworld-example-app/blob/f323b015e3b0a6abbe8ac49170c66de9c32fe931/lib/src/common/middleware/authorize.dart

```dart
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/jwt_service.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/users_service.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';

Middleware authorize(UsersService usersService, JwtService jwtService,
        List<String> routesRequiringAuthorization) =>
    (innerHandler) {
      return (request) async {
        var isAuthorizationRequired =
            routesRequiringAuthorization.contains(request.url.path);

        if (isAuthorizationRequired) {
          final authorizationHeader = request.headers['Authorization'] ??
              request.headers['authorization'];

          if (authorizationHeader == null) {
            return Response(401);
          }

          if (!authorizationHeader.startsWith('Token ')) {
            return Response(401);
          }

          final token = authorizationHeader.replaceFirst('Token', '').trim();

          if (token.isEmpty) {
            return Response(401);
          }

          final userTokenClaim = jwtService.getUserTokenClaim(token);

          if (userTokenClaim == null) {
            return Response(401);
          }

          final user = await usersService.getUserByEmail(userTokenClaim.email);

          if (user == null) {
            return Response(401);
          }

          request = request.change(context: {'user': user});
        }

        return Future.sync(() => innerHandler(request)).then((response) {
          return response;
        });
      };
    };
```

https://github.com/marcusmonteirodesouza/dart-shelf-realworld-example-app/blob/f323b015e3b0a6abbe8ac49170c66de9c32fe931/lib/app.dart

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/app_router.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/common/middleware/authorize.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/jwt_service.dart';
import 'package:dart_shelf_realworld_example_app/src/users/users_service.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';

Future<HttpServer> createServer() async {
  final authSecretKey = Platform.environment['AUTH_SECRET_KEY'];
  final authIssuer = Platform.environment['AUTH_ISSUER'];
  final dbHost = Platform.environment['DB_HOST'];
  final envDbPort = Platform.environment['DB_PORT'];
  final dbName = Platform.environment['DB_NAME'];
  final dbUser = Platform.environment['DB_USER'];
  final dbPassword = Platform.environment['DB_PASSWORD'];

  if (authSecretKey == null) {
    throw StateError('Environment variable AUTH_SECRET_KEY is required');
  }

  if (authIssuer == null) {
    throw StateError('Environment variable AUTH_ISSUER is required');
  }

  if (dbHost == null) {
    throw ArgumentError('Environment variable DB_HOST must be an integer');
  }

  if (envDbPort == null) {
    throw StateError('Environment variable DB_PORT is required');
  }

  if (dbName == null) {
    throw StateError('Environment variable DB_NAME is required');
  }

  final dbPort = int.tryParse(envDbPort);

  if (dbPort == null) {
    throw ArgumentError('Environment variable DB_PORT must be an integer');
  }

  final connection = PostgreSQLConnection(dbHost, dbPort, dbName,
      username: dbUser, password: dbPassword);

  await connection.open();

  final usersService = UsersService(connection: connection);
  final jwtService = JwtService(issuer: authIssuer, secretKey: authSecretKey);

  final router =
      AppRouter(jwtService: jwtService, usersService: usersService).router;

  // Use any available host or container IP (usually `0.0.0.0`).
  final ip = InternetAddress.anyIPv4;

  // Configure a pipeline that logs requests.
  final handler = Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(logRequests())
      .addMiddleware(authorize(
          usersService, jwtService, AppRouter.routesRequiringAuthorization))
      .addHandler(router);

  final port = int.parse(Platform.environment['PORT'] ?? '8080');

  // For running in containers, we respect the PORT environment variable.
  final server = await serve(handler, ip, port);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
  return server;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a better way: the handlers in `shelf` are composable, and by using the [`Pipeline`](https://pub.dev/documentation/shelf/latest/shelf/Pipeline-class.html) class we can add middleware to compose handlers that will then be added to the router.

https://github.com/marcusmonteirodesouza/dart-shelf-realworld-example-app/blob/04dddb250592061986aa23d823cfee6ff37a5ab6/lib/src/users/users_router.dart#L155

```dart
Handler get router {
    final router = Router();

    router.post('/users', _registerUserHandler);

    router.post('/users/login', _loginUserHandler);

    router.get(
        '/user',
        Pipeline()
            .addMiddleware(authorize(usersService, jwtService))
            .addHandler(_getCurrentUserHandler));

    router.put(
        '/user',
        Pipeline()
            .addMiddleware(authorize(usersService, jwtService))
            .addHandler(_updateUserHandler));

    return router;
  }
```

This way, I could have fine grained control over which routes would require authentication and which would not by adding or not the middleware on them individually.